# How can i use multiple implements?

Tags: android, implements

I'm making App with Android Studio.

I have a

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener
```

And I need to add "AppCompatActivity" to the MainActivity.

I have searched on the Internet and I found only one can be used for extends.

So I Changed to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener, AppCompatActivity
```

This and AppCompatActivity has an error that "Interface expected here".

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AppCompatActivity` is a class not an interface  so you can't use `implements` keyword  to inherit the `AppCompatActivity`

You need to use `extends` keyword to inherit the `AppCompatActivity` class

Use this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener
```

instead of

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener, AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: after i changed Activity, There is an Error.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
I think I shouldn't change Activity

Comment: @문경욱 for that issue please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/21814825/7666442

Answer (score 0):

The 'Interface expected here' occurs when you implement a class, not an interface.
`AppCompatActivity` is a class which you are not able to implement.

I don't know why you want to extend from `Activity` in addition to`AppCompatActivity`, `AppCompatActivity` inherits from `Activity` already.

```
AppCompatActivity > FragmentActivity > SupportActivity > Activity
```

Just write:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {
```

There is no need to extend `Activity` for you when you do it like that.